# Non-transactional unit test with spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, transactions

Hi I have a unit test which should test a cronjob

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@Transactional
public class cronTest {}
```

but due to the transaction the cronjob doesn't see the data of the test. But when I remove the @Transactional Hibernate says:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

when I commit by my own

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

the test fails at the end

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
```

How can I get an unit test without transaction?

the Test does someting like that:

```
    userDao.clear();
    loadeduser = userService.getUserById(createUser.getUserID());
    assertTrue(loadeduser.getAuthoritiesEntities().contains(adminRole));
    assertTrue(loadeduser.getAuthoritiesEntities().contains(userRole));

    // Wait for auto unsign
    TestUtils.sleep(10000);

    userDao.clear();
    loadeduser = userService.getUserById(createUser.getUserID());
    assertFalse(loadeduser.getAuthoritiesEntities().contains(adminRole));
    assertTrue(loadeduser.getAuthoritiesEntities().contains(userRole));
```

it checks if the auto unsign of expired roles works, the quartz job runs every 5 secs

Comment: Can you add more of the content of crontTest()? I'd like to see method calls of the subject under test, and the placement of the sessionFactory methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I'd recommend using unit tests for code that can be tested within a single transaction, and integration tests (bringing up the full system and exercising the sequence you want to test) to test multi-transactional behavior.

But to answer the question: One way around this is to remove the @Transaction from the test method as you've done, but instead of making the test method control transactions directly, allow the methods you're testing to begin/commit their own transactions (which they will normally be doing anyway, right?)

For instance, we might have tests that run through a normal DAO workflow, and each DAO method is marked as @Transactional. Each method controls its own transaction commits, so we can test multi-transactional behavior in a single test method. That test might look like this:

```
// no @Transactional here, dao methods are @Transactional
public void testMultiTransactionUpdate() {
    Entity t = dao.getEntity(id);
    t.setProperty("somethingnew");
    dao.update(t);
    Entity t2 = dao.getEntity(id);
    Assert.assertEquals(t1.getProperty(), t2.getProperty());
}
```

One thing to be careful of is that if you are committing against an in-memory database (like HSQLDB), your changes made in one test will not be automatically rolled back and will normally be visible to subsequent tests. You will have to manually undo all of your changes at the end of the test, or ensure that your test data does not interfere with other tests which is not so easy. That's why I would use this technique sparingly.

Comment: hi i need such a test because i want to ensure that quartz is configured properly. I'm calling a service which is Transactional, but without the Transactional in the test i get "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread"

Comment: Can you add the test code to your question? Something in your test is calling code that requires a session to be open and I can't see what that is. Normally, careful placement of @Transactional on your service methods is sufficient.

Comment: Alternatively, you can leave Transactional on your test and add defaultRollback=false to your TransactionConfiguration, and test what you want to test in an After annotaed method. In that case you might want this to be the only test in the class.

Comment: Thanks for including the test code. Also can you include more of the stack trace for When you remove @Transactional from the unit test? I'm curious where in your code the exception is being thrown. More questions: What does userDao.clear() do? Is userService.getUserById() itself marked as @Transactional? Have you ensured that loadedUser's authorities are fully loaded before returning from the service? (although if they weren't I'd more expect a LazyInitializationException)

Comment: Also, your code works when you run a manual test right? Make sure that the sequence of calls in your test method is the same as the sequence of calls in a live manual test. Again, each method in your test should have its own transactional boundaries, and there should be no method calls that attempt to access the current session without controlling its own transaction.

Comment: hi you where right: the userDao was not transactional, thanks